# delete unmatched records from first table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I have table 1 and table 2 - the left join representation, we can think of as below-

[image]

I want to perform delete on table 1 as below  - the orange hi-lighted part shoud get deleted

[image]

I was trying something like this - but it does not work.

```
  delete from  MY_SCHEMA.TABLE1 DL   LEFT JOIN MY_SCHEMA.TABLE2  ERR_TB on 
   DL.DL_ID1 = ERR_TB.ERR_ID1    and  DL.DL_ID2 = ERR_TB.ERR_ID2   ;
```

is it possible to perform delete as shown in figure-2. I want to delete orange records from table 1.

Any help is appreciated, thank you in Advance :)
   Note - there are no PK and FK here , table1 and table2 have - 2 same columns - which are not inter related or dependent

Comment: `delete from  MY_SCHEMA.TABLE1 where ID2 NOT IN (SELECT ID2 from TABLE2)`

Comment: **"As we all know"**? I don't know that. Actually I know that the graphical representation you show is 100% wrong, no matter how many fools present it as some clever depiction of joins. (And I do have some credibility - I am a retired mathematics university professor.) Venn diagrams are for union, intersection, minus. Joins are subsets of CARTESIAN PRODUCTS, and Cartesian products can't be illustrated with Venn diagrams. Sorry, but I stopped reading your post after that sentence.

Comment: @jarlh - That is dangerous. Perhaps `ID2` is foreign key in `TABLE2`, which in particular would allow it to be `NULL`. If `NULL` is present in that column, then `NOT IN` will give the wrong result. You must use `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: @mathguy, I wouldn't say _dangerous_. If the subquery returns null values, no rows will be deleted.

Comment: @jarlh - An incorrect query (or a query that may be incorrect in some cases) may result in one of two things. It may end up throwing an error - either always or only on some data - or it may simply produce the wrong result without ever throwing an error (so one may never know that something is wrong). I call everything in the second category "dangerous". To me, that means "incorrect, and in a way you may never realize it's incorrect."

Comment: @mathguy, good point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to filter out the matching rows. 
The remaining rows are the ones with no counterpart in `table2` and these will be deleted.

```
DELETE FROM MY_SCHEMA.table1 DL 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM table2 ERR_TB 
     WHERE ERR_TB.id1 = DL.id1 
       AND ERR_TB.id2 = DL.id2
)
```

The above code is based on your `join` statement. 
If you want only `ERR_TB.id1 = DL.id1` or `ERR_TB.id2 = DL.id2` then use 1 of the following:

```
DELETE FROM MY_SCHEMA.table1 DL 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM table2 ERR_TB 
     WHERE ERR_TB.id1 = DL.id1 
)
```

or

```
DELETE FROM MY_SCHEMA.table1 DL 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM table2 ERR_TB 
     WHERE  ERR_TB.id2 = DL.id2
)
```

Comment: this is not working - tried - it says 0 rows deleted

Comment: Then maybe the join statement that you wrote: `on 
   DL.ID1 = ERR_TB.ID1    and  DL.ID2 = ERR_TB.ID` is not what you want.

Comment: yes - this will give me complete table 1. I want to delete the orange hi-lighted part as i have shown in figure 2

Comment: *I want to delete the orange hi-lighted part as i have shown in figure 2* based on what? Did you try the statement with `SELECT 1 FROM table2 ERR_TB 
     WHERE ERR_TB.id1 = DL.id1`?

Comment: I need to delete based on combination of both columns , not just one

Answer (score 1):

you may try `not exists` :

```
delete my_schema.table1 t1 
 where not exists ( select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id2 );
```

or `minus` :

```
delete my_schema.table1
 where id2 in ( select t1.id2 from table1 t1 minus
                select t2.id  from table2 t2  );
```

[***dbfiddle uk demo***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0ce87f2873bb61017546eafd097f5e30)

Comment: Only use `MINUS` when it is absolutely needed, since it's much slower than other operations. (For one thing, it de-duplicates; whether you do need that or not, it's done anyway, and it's expensive). Then: if ID2 was FK in TABLE 1, how could it ever NOT be in the list of ID's from TABLE 2? More likely, it is PK in TABLE 1, and the children are in TABLE 2 (and you want to remove the PK's that aren't used).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, I hope it will help you:

```
delete t1 from table1 t1
join table2 t2
on t1.id1 = t2.id1
where t1.id1 = t2.id1 and t1.id2 = t2.id2
```